# Geolocation API: Requested entity was not found

Tags: google-geolocation

I am trying Geolocation API for first time, but not able to get it working.
Trying a sample from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview but always returning me 404. I already have billing enabled for this project.

Request Body:

```
{
  "homeMobileCountryCode": 412
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound"
            }
        ],
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem here, working with Postman. Doesn't matter what info I provide them. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Still same problem. I gave up :)

Comment: Does anyone got a solution  ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same issue. Then I looked up my billing account which was not linked. After linking it I tried to request it again via postman and it does give me a response with lat long and accuracy

**Request 1**

```
{
  "considerIp": "true",
  "wifiAccessPoints": [
   {
     "macAddress": "00:1e:32:f2:32:ff"
  }

  ]
}
```

**Request 2**

```
{
     "homeMobileCountryCode": 412
}
```

**Response against both the request**

```
{
"location": {
    "lat": 31.473738999999995,
    "lng": 74.253135
},
"accuracy": 1528
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can confirm that disabled billing was also giving me 404 errors. I would never have thought to look at billing - they should really return a different error code.